# How to find source of faulty included file

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, filereference

Sencha Touch will complain about files it can't find a lot. Usually you just include the file. But sometimes the problem is a faulty include. So then you need to find where the file is being requested. Since it won't tell you where the require is located, that can be a problem.

Currently I have another such file. Tried something, it didn't work, now I want the files out of my project. But somehow Sencha Touch keeps looking for it. I've tried:

- Find specifically in the locations it was included
- Find in bootstrap.js
- Find All for the file name
- Rebuild of the project with Sencha CMD (complains about the same problem)
- Empty cache and hard reload in Chrome
- Other browsers, they crash even worse

Anyone have a trick to find remaining requires in Sencha Touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the file name without the extension. As most requires don't have the file extension in them (including this one) I was not finding anything based on a search that included the extension...

Comment: Have you checked in error stack? can you paste it here for reference?

Comment: Yea the error stack is how you know which file is missing. I'm working somewhere else now, don't have access to the code.